# SVN : Create patch with log message

Tags: svn

I'm using Tortoise SVN on Windows.
I want to delay commit (for quality reason and because I want to perform a slow transition to Git for a dev team), so I want to use patch before commit. Don't know if it's a good practice but nevermind, here is my question : **can I make in a single file a diff patch + a log comment ?** (I know I can zip files but maybe there is something else !)

Hope my question is clear enough, thanks in advance for help !

Comment: Why not use CR-branch for code-review (and merge reviewed revisions into trunk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure Subversion - no, you can't

Comment: Ok, thanks! (sigh) I will wait for one or two days for another answer (don't know if there is another possibility) before validating your answer.